# Visualisation with Vega Lite : "emoji undefined"

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, vega-lite, vega

I'm trying to reproduce a visualisation in Vega Lite (https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/isotype_bar_chart_emoji.html). Instead of the animals emoji, I chose emoji to symbolise energy source. However my code does not work, looks like Vega does not recognise the emojis as it labels : "undefined". How can I help vega so it uses emojis as logos ?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "config": {"view": {"stroke": ""}},
  "width": 800,
  "height": 200,
  "data": {
    "values": [
{"continent": "Africa", "share": "coal"},
{"continent": "Africa", "share": "coal"},
{"continent": "Africa", "share": "gas"},
{"continent": "Europe", "share": "gas"},
{"continent": "Europe", "share": "gas"},
{"continent": "Europe", "share": "hydro"},
{"continent": "Europe", "share": "nuclear"},
{"continent": "Europe", "share": "renewables"},
{"continent": "Europe", "share": "renewables"},
{"continent": "Europe", "share": "renewables"},
{"continent": "Europe", "share": "renewables"},
{"continent": "Europe", "share": "renewables"}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "{'coal': '', 'nuclear': '⚛️', 'oil': '️','renewables':'♻️','gas':'⛽'}",
      "as": "emoji"
    },
    {"window": [{"op": "rank", "as": "rank"}], "groupby": ["continent", "share"]}
  ],
  "mark": {"type": "text", "baseline": "middle"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "rank", "type": "ordinal", "axis": null},
    "y": {"field": "share", "type": "nominal", "axis": null, "sort": null},
    "row": {"field": "continent", "header": {"title": ""}},
    "text": {"field": "emoji", "type": "nominal"},
    "size": {"value": 65}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transform calculate was not proper, you can use the `datum` to access the field from your data and depending on the condition provide the `emoji` value. Refer the below code or the [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQUOQDMaZNKGI04Ady0gImAE5sA1nDQgQAX1tK9NACb00ADgAMnpfA1Y0ACZvJWckTBRUbSRBBjgINABtUBVZTBpZODTrAEFVExooFCUIGCQTK3QVGLsFFLl0zOz0PIKixSMyiutqwVr6tIyszFz8wuLO8sqQCgSHAcbh6wBRBjMcKxKu6dn+5Qah5pBV9c3J7vRd+f3BppH0E7YNjtKp6xgAT2czPdTFo8ezy2b3QsgYUEEcHKvwOdxWayeZ1eFxAFUyeiQTEhczqN3+92OCKB52maP0mOxMNuSweRKR22sZIxWPiVPx8NOLwZ6CZFNZ1z+hwJgPpINRWXJLLmAF0HCBTEhZBBVGwTAgkikYlAGIJwtMwpgGAhKMi4AACAC8FrNAHJejazQB+M22wA8G4Bb-YdqDNBqNJu2lutNrBEKhJgdzptgGyyQDwf16feE-abA7a2DRBBHbYBeDcAR3txs3e33G5NW228qURm2AbzJ896bYBfshtHSQCXQiDYkhoeycsmcbAMqGSICejMV5mbrdRY7s0qUZDMDBwTA+STxQq5b1ls5AyBM46i8o+z3QmDgAA8RkomC24MJMtYEC5nJDaiAsipnBlNAez4Z1LfnFHWRxyUTAj2mVVP1kGolCQM8aFbMFBEEOUVwPf9BEA9BTQ6MDjxAWQ2EfaC+lg+DEJ1QQSlVe4kJQpQzAHUAMKwtc4V8KFnDgExDHSTAX3QOw5VPC8-10TDrHbTtcPA6xCOImo5QgGgAC9KmiWJKgANjEexbCAA)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "config": {"view": {"stroke": ""}},
  "width": 800,
  "height": 200,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"continent": "Africa", "share": "coal"},
      {"continent": "Africa", "share": "coal"},
      {"continent": "Africa", "share": "gas"},
      {"continent": "Europe", "share": "gas"},
      {"continent": "Europe", "share": "gas"},
      {"continent": "Europe", "share": "hydro"},
      {"continent": "Europe", "share": "nuclear"},
      {"continent": "Europe", "share": "renewables"},
      {"continent": "Europe", "share": "renewables"},
      {"continent": "Europe", "share": "renewables"},
      {"continent": "Europe", "share": "renewables"},
      {"continent": "Europe", "share": "renewables"}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "datum.share == 'coal' ?  '' : datum.share == 'nuclear' ? '⚛️' : datum.share == 'oil' ? '️' : datum.share == 'renewables' ?'♻️' : '⛽'",
      "as": "emoji"
    },
    {
      "window": [{"op": "rank", "as": "rank"}],
      "groupby": ["continent", "share"]
    }
  ],
  "mark": {"type": "text", "baseline": "middle"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "rank", "type": "ordinal", "axis": null},
    "y": {"field": "share", "type": "nominal", "axis": null, "sort": null},
    "row": {"field": "continent", "header": {"title": ""}},
    "text": {"field": "emoji", "type": "nominal"},
    "size": {"value": 65}
  }
}
```

or simple adding this line to your current code will also resolve the issue:

```
{
  "calculate": "{'coal': '', 'nuclear': '⚛️', 'oil': '️','renewables':'♻️','gas':'⛽', 'hydro': '',}[datum.share]",
  "as": "emoji"
}
```